# When you click on the button in the console displays the name of the button and the product is not filtered

Tags: reactjs

Good day everyone, I am implementing filtering functionality for a price. I have a function that implements this. When I click on the button, the name of the button itself is displayed in my console, and the product itself is not filtered. Tell me, please, what can it be? The screenshots show the console and my code are infected. Help me please.

app.js file where the whole program is located

```
import Navbar from './components/Navsbar'
import {useState} from "react"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import {ListProduct} from "./ListProduct";
import data from "./service/data";
import {Home} from './Home'
import AppFilter from './components/Filter';

//import Footer from 'rc-table/lib/Footer';


function App() {

  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(data)
 const [field,setState] =  useState([]);
  
 
  
  const searchTerm = (items, term,number) => {
    let lower = term.toLowerCase();
    if (term.length === 0) return items;
    return items.filter((item) => {
      let itemLower = item.strDrink.toLowerCase()
        return itemLower.indexOf(lower)> -1;
      });
    
  };

  const onUpdateSearch = (term) => {
    setFilter(term);
  };

 const filterPost =(items,field)=>{
    switch(field){
        
        case 'moreThen1000':
            return items.filter(item=>item.price > 500);
            default:
                return items
    }
}
 const onFilterSelect =(field) =>{
 setState(field);
 console.log(field)
};
 
  const visible =  searchTerm(info.drinks, filter)
  const viewable = filterPost(info.drinks,field)

  return (
    <>
     
    <Router>
    <Navbar onUpdateSearch={onUpdateSearch} />
    <AppFilter filter={field} onFilterSelect={onFilterSelect}/>
    
    <Routes>
    
    <Route exact path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route exact path="/ListProduct" element={<ListProduct searchTerm = {visible}  onFilterSelect={viewable}/>} />
 
    
    </Routes>
   
    </Router>
 
  
    </>
  );
}



export default App;
```

appFilter.js file where the buttons are stored

```
import React from 'react';
import './Filter.css';
import data from "../service/data";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";



const AppFilter = (props) => {
    const buttonsData = [
        {name: 'all', label: 'All cocktails'},
     
        {name: 'moreThen1000', label: 'More expensive than 500$'}
    ];

    const buttons = buttonsData.map(({name, label}) => {
        const active = props.filter === name;
        const clazz = active ? 'btn-light' : 'btn-outline-light';
        return (
            <button type="button"
                    className={`btn ${clazz}`}
                    key={name}
                    onClick={() => props.onFilterSelect(name)}>
                    {label}
            </button>
        )
    })
   
    


    return (
        <div className="btn-group">
            {buttons}
        </div>
    )
}

export default AppFilter;
```

ListProduct.js file where cards with goods are displayed

```
import "./ListProduct.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { Container, Row, Col, Card } from "react-bootstrap";

  export const ListProduct = (props) => {
  const {searchTerm, onFilterSelect} = props
  const element = searchTerm.map((item, i) => {
    const { strDrinkThumb, strDrink, price } = item;
  

    return (
      
      <div className="card">
        <li key={i}>
          <Container>
            <Row>
              <Col>
                <Card  style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                  <Card.Img variant="top" src={strDrinkThumb} />
                  <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>{strDrink}</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                     { `Alcohol shop . The price is for one glass
                      ${price}$`}
                    </Card.Text>
                  </Card.Body>
                </Card>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Container>
        </li>
        
      </div>
    );
  });

  return <div  className="site">
  <ul>{ element}</ul>
  <div>
<footer className="page-footer font-small blue pt-4">
    <div className="container-fluid text-center text-md-left">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-md-6 mt-md-0 mt-3">
                <h5 className="text-uppercase">Cocktail shop</h5>
                <p>Modern cocktail shop for different choices</p>
            </div>

            <hr className="clearfix w-100 d-md-none pb-0"/>

            <div className="col-md-3 mb-md-0 mb-3">
                <h5 className="text-uppercase">Our online resources</h5>
                <ul className="list-unstyled">
                    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/cocktail_sol/">Our instagram page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/">Our site</a></li>
                  
                </ul>
            </div>

            
           
        </div>
    </div>

    <div className="footer-copyright text-center py-3">© 2020 Copyright:
        <a href="https://mdbootstrap.com/"> MDBootstrap.com</a>
    </div>

</footer>
</div>
  </div>;
};
```

Comment: You are passing down searchTerm and onFilterSelect props into ListProduct, but inside actual component you don't do anything with it.

Comment: In the program file I have a function that does filtering through switch.Isn't that something, because I did according to the model and everything worked there.

Comment: Yeah, I see. You are using it, storing result in "viewable" variable and pass it down to ListProduct. And you don't use it inside ListProduct at all. So it may be the actual reason :)

Comment: That is, I need to take a variable   "viewable" and transfer it to a file List Product. Whether the variable should be used in the program file?